# Como cambiar este icono de boton en react native?

Tags: android, react-native

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en react native el cual he compilado en un celular android, y he visto que el icono de este boton se puede cambiar por el de la segunda imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe como cambiarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar la propiedad `returnKeyType` de `TextInput`.

```
<TextInput style={{height:40}} 
       placeholder="Input"
       placeholderTextColor="#DCDCDC"
       returnKeyType="next"
/>
```

Las opciones de dicha propiedad son:

- go
- next
- done
- search
- end

Me parece que el botón que buscas es `next`. Te recomendaría experimentar con las propiedades hasta encontrar la que necesites.

A su vez, hay otras opciones específicas para iOS y otras para Android, por lo que te recomiendo leer [la documentación](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput) para saber más sobre las diferentes opciones.

Comment: ¡Gracias! Si me ha funcionado